# How to reduce request to my database?

Tags: database, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

i have a partial view with a gridview in it. so when user clicks add button request will redirect to Add method of unitsController. After add it to database I should refetch all data from database. Is there a way to prevent controller from get all database records?

Below is my current controller

```
public class UnitsController : Controller
{
    TList<Units> model=null;

    public ActionResult UnitsPartial()
    {
        if(model==null)
          model = database.GetAll();
        return PartialView(model);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Add(Units unit)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            database.Save(unit);
            model.Add(unit);          
        }

        return PartialView("UnitsPartial", model);
    }
```

In the last line I want to use `return PartialView("UnitsPartial", model)` instead of `return database.GetAll()` to prevent a database query.  But model is null in Add method.
Is my approach correct or not?  And why is model is null in add() method?
--UPDATED
first of all control redirect to UnitsPartial() and will fill model object correctly. after press add button, control will redirect to Add(...) method but this time model is equal to null !!! 
what is the problem with it? i tried to pass model.Clone() to partial view
`return PartialView("UnitsPartial", model.Clone());`
but the result is the same

Comment: What do you mean by "Why is model is null in add() method?  As a code line that is not in the add method.  If you mean "why does model equal null in Add" then it would be null until you add the first unit.

Comment: @BalamBalam i update my question please read it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't cache values in the controller class like this using member variables.  HTTP is stateless and MVC 3 follows that approach.  Each individual call to an action method is going to have a brand new instance of Controller class with the model set to null.

So start by calling `database.GetAll()` in both action methods and then ask the question "How do I make this more efficient".

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it is the right approach or not, since I do not fully understand what you try to do, but your model is null because you initialize it as null when the controller is created. you should do a model = new TList() before adding something to it....

Comment: the problem is pressing the add button is a new request which creates a new instance of the controller. When this is done, model is set to null upon creation of the controller, and still null when the Add method is executed. You need to set the model to something.

Comment: uhhh! am i in the wrong way totally? but wait i declared a bool variable and it`s worked! but model still is equal to null! that means controller is not such stateless!!!

Comment: I am not following you about the boolean, but again: When you press the Add button, a new request is done to the server, this creates a total new UnitsController object, upon creation `TList<Units> model=null;` is set, before executing the `public ActionResult Add(Units unit)` method. So, inside your add method, *model* is still NULL, either set it by doing `model = database.GetAll()` or create a new TList object. The fact that the model == null at the second request means that it **is** stateless